# GIT-SVN fixing history of tag which is not whole copy of branch/trunk

Tags: git, svn

I am working on large project in SVN and I am using GIT-SVN.

Following illustrate my problem in 
SVN
  trunk
     |- kernel1
     |- kernel2
     |- custom1
     |- custom2
  branches
     |-kernel_RC1
        |- kernel1
        |- kernel2

Problem is that branch kernel_RC1 with its children is created in one commit and GIT-SVN did not recognise that kernel_RC1/kernel1 is a copy of trunk/kernel1 and those the history is broken here and looks like it was created from scratch.

Is there way how to configure GIT-SVN to find those copy of branch child folder to show the history correctly?